# Resizing Google+ photos from standard to full size

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

I have lost hard copies of a number of photos and they are saved in Google plus and Picaso. They were saved as the smaller, standard size photos. Because of the lower quality, I cannot utilize them for books or printing, only web-based programs. Is there a way to restore or change them to original resolution without a hard copy?

Answer (score 2):

If you had Google+ backup standard sized photos than that is the resolution stored in the cloud. There is no way to get higher resolution without having the original images.